# combine two different length videos frame by frame so as they appear in one frame, kind of like video tiling

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, video-capture, video-processing

I have two h264 videos of different length but same resolution (640,480). I want to combine them frame by frame such that frame f1 of video1 at time T and frame f2 of video2 at time T appear in one frame sideways. So finally you have a video formed by combining sequence of frames from video1 and video2.

How can I do this using any of these solution:

- programming
- softwares
- ffmpeg

Comment: You should ask [specific questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) explaining what you already tried.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do. Can you provide an image representing what you want?

Comment: In OpenCV: your resulting image `Mat3b res` will be 1280x480. You can have the left one as `Mat3b left(res(Rect(0,0,640,480)));` and right one as `Mat3b right(res(Rect(640,0,640,480)));`. Then you just need to copy the frames in correct position: `leftFrame.copyTo(left); rightFrame.copyTo(right)`. Remember to `waitKey` after `imshow`. For a better answer you need to narrow down your question and post what you've tried so far, else is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem using this:

```
import cv2
import cv
import numpy as np

capture1 = cv2.VideoCapture("video1.h264")
capture2 = cv2.VideoCapture("video2.h264")

while True:
    ret1, frame1 = capture1.read()
    ret2, frame2 = capture2.read()

    h1, w1, d1 = capture1.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT), capture1.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), 3
    h2, w2, d2 = capture1.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT), capture1.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), 3

    vis = np.zeros((max(h1,h2), w1+w2, 3), np.uint8)
    if frame1 is None:
        frame1 = np.zeros((h1,w1,d1), np.uint8)
    if frame2 is None:
        frame2 = np.zeros((h2,w2,d2), np.uint8)

    vis[:h1, :w1, :d1] = frame1
    vis[:h2, w1:w1+w2, :d2] = frame2

    cv2.imshow('Merged Frame', vis)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break 

capture1.release()
capture2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Above code addresses the issue of different length of videos as well. For example: say video1 is longer video2, then video2 side will go dark till video1 ends.

But there is another issue which is that after video2 goes dark, the processing of video1 slows down. Also how should I break the loop once both the videos have ended? I was trying to use `ret1, ret2 flags` mentioned but they are not working apparrently